# Keybord back light

Tags: keyboard

Good morning, I have a problem with my keybord: with ubuntu 16,04 LTs my keybord back lights don't work, furthermore whe the screen goes to energy saving mode , when I try to log in again the keybord doesn't work at all.what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

That's an odd error... usually, keyboard backlighting isn't entirely system controlled. On most laptops it's controlled by using F5.

What's the make and model of your machine?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer,my pc is a sony vaio model sve141d11l